# How to set column name for Hashmap's value with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Consider the following annotations :

```
    public class Estate {

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "estates_owners")
        @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="owner_id")
        public Map<Owner, Share> getOwnerSharesMap() {
            return ownerSharesMap;
        }

    }
```

Hibernate creates a table `estates_owners` with following column names:

```
estate_id | ownersharesmap_id | owner_id
```

How can I customize the column named `ownersharesmap_id`? I want to rename it to `share_id`.

Comment: @Tunaki where should i put it? it wont compile if i add it to mapKeyJoinColumn and it seems to be the only possible place

Comment: that's wrong `@MapKeyJoinColumn`, applies to the map key which is from `Owner` entity. The question is how to set the column name of the map value which is of `Share` entity. referencedColumnName won't achieve the desired result.

Comment: @Tunaki as i said this is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a `inverseJoinColumns` in your `@JoinTable` annotation.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "estates_owners",
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="share_id"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name="owner_id")
public Map<Owner, Share> getOwnerSharesMap() {
    return ownerSharesMap;
}
```

Comment: sorry, use `inverseJoinColumns` instead. Updated my answer

Comment: seems that it is working, let me chek for any side effects and i will come back to you